# PhP catchable fatal error when using mysqli_stmt

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have tried searching the forumn but could not fix my fatal error when coding my php prepared statement.

Im using a prepared statement to prevent sql injection and also prevent error when user inputs apostrophe. Below is my code:

submit_data.php

```
<?php
include "../connect.php";

$message_form = $_POST['message'];
$username_form = $_POST['user'];

// $insert_data=$db->query("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message,user) VALUES ('$message_form','$username_form')");

$insert_data=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message,user) VALUES (?, ?)");

$insert_data->bind_param("ss", $message_form, $username_form);
$insert_data->execute();


if ($insert_data === TRUE ){
    echo "New record created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert_data . "<br>" . $db->error;
  }

$insert_data->close();
$db->close();
?>
```

my connection file to the database( connect.php)

```
<?php

            $host = "localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $pass = ""; 

            $database_name = "test"; 
            $table_name = "test_table_1";  

            //connect to mysql database
            $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database_name); 
            //check connection
            if ($db -> connect_error) {
                die("error mysql database not connected: " . $db -> connect_error);
            }
            // else {
            //  echo "connected successfully" ; //enable this for debugging purpose 
            // }            

?>
```

This is the error i am receiving

> **Catchable fatal error**:
>       Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string in 
>           **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/z_admin/submit_data.php**
>        on line **19**

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't echo `$db->error` in this line because it contain object of your database connection

```
echo "Error: " . $insert_data . "<br>" . $db->error;
```

Instead Use  `affected_rows` Returns the auto generated id used in the last query

```
if ($insert_data->affected_rows >0){
    echo "New record created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Not inserted";
  }
```

Comment: i see thank you for your help. yes there isn't an error now. what do u mean  by object from database? @Saty

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code as this

connect.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = ""; 

$database_name = "test"; 
$table_name = "test_table_1";  

//connect to mysql database
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database_name);
```

submit_data.php

```
<?php
include "../connect.php";

$stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO test_table_1(message,user) VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['message'], $_POST['user']);
$stmt->execute();
echo "New record created successfully";
```

This method adds best error checking you can ever imagine.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, but was hoping to print out to console if error exist,  yes your method works too as it remove the error checking.